# Swing : GridBagLayout adding components not the expected way

Tags: java, swing, constraints, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm just trying to use the GridBagLayout following [this](https://openclassrooms.com/courses/apprenez-a-programmer-en-java/positionner-des-boutons) tutorial.

I can't get what I want to have.

I would want each Panel to take as much space as possible but it is not the case, I really tried everything, following the steps in the [Oracle Docs](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAAahUKEwix94iP6uDIAhUBCBoKHQg-D3M&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2Ftutorial%2Fuiswing%2Flayout%2Fgridbag.html&usg=AFQjCNF6mowfJUc7K9kcGk4IibSTwupBvw)

But the result is always the same :

[image: GBC]

I really do not understand why the layout is not working.

I tried changing the layout of the JFrame, setting the panel as ContentPane(), tried to add the constraints found on both websites, nothing seems to work.

Your help will is appreciated.

---

**Full Code**

```
public class Monitor extends JFrame{

    // Menu
    private JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
    private JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    private JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem("Open");
    private JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");

    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

    private JPanel secondaryPanel;
    private JPanel explorerPanel, tagPanel;

    public Monitor(){
        setTitle("");
        setSize(750,600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);


        initComps();
    }

    public void initComps(){

        explorerPanel = new JPanel();
        explorerPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        explorerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,300));

        tagPanel = new JPanel();
        tagPanel.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        tagPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 300));

        secondaryPanel = new JPanel();
        secondaryPanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
        secondaryPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 600));

        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750, 600));
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.gridx = 0 ; gbc.gridy = 0 ; gbc.gridwidth = 1 ; gbc.gridheight = 1;
        mainPanel.add(explorerPanel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1 ; gbc.gridy = 0 ; gbc.gridwidth = 2 ; gbc.gridheight = 2;
        mainPanel.add(secondaryPanel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0 ; gbc.gridy = 1 ; gbc.gridwidth = 1 ; gbc.gridheight = 1;
        mainPanel.add(tagPanel, gbc);

        this.setContentPane(mainPanel);

        // Menu Bar
        file.add(open);

        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        exit.setMnemonic('q');
        file.add(exit);

        bar.add(file);
        setJMenuBar(bar);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Monitor().setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

---

**EDIT :**

When adding

```
gbc.weightx = 1;
gbc.weighty = 1;
```

**Result**

[image: GBC]

Comment: See: http://madbean.com/anim/totallygridbag/ and also http://www.miglayout.com/ to avoid going insane.

Comment: @Yar Thank you for the advice. Do you think it is somehow possible using GBL?

Comment: Yes, it's probably possible. But MigLayout makes everybody happy forever and ever.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire probably the best indeed. Now that the question is asked, I wait for a correct answer though. Learning something more I hope. :) But thanks for the advice in either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from your dimensions.

Don't use "preferred" only. Use minimum as well.

```
explorerPanel = new JPanel();
explorerPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
explorerPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(250, 300));
explorerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 300));

tagPanel = new JPanel();
tagPanel.setBackground(Color.yellow);
tagPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(250, 300));
tagPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 300));

secondaryPanel = new JPanel();
secondaryPanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
secondaryPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 600));
secondaryPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 600));

mainPanel = new JPanel();
mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750, 600));
mainPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(750, 600));
mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
```

This worked in my test:[image]

Comment: This is satisfying :) Merci Olivier de Bruxelles. You're warmly thanked.

Comment: You might want to use `GridBagConstraints.fill` as well. I barely touched any GBL/GBC in years, but I remember it was somehow important.

Comment: will definitely do. Have a nice evening

Comment: using `setXXXSize` with GridBagLayout is not recommended as it is notorious for ignoring them.

Comment: Using `GridBagLayout` is not recommended as it is notorious to cause brain damage :P

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `GridBagConstraints.weightx` and `GridBagConstraints.weighty` to something non-zero:

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html)

> **GridBagConstraints.weightx, GridBagConstraints.weighty**
>
> Used to determine how to distribute space, which is important for specifying resizing behavior. Unless you specify a weight for at least one component in a row (weightx) and column (weighty), all the components clump together in the center of their container. This is because when the weight is zero (the default), the GridBagLayout object puts any extra space between its grid of cells and the edges of the container.

Setting it to 1 for all of the components should work fine if you want them all to fill up the space.

There is also more explanation of these fields on the [Oracle tutorial page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) you linked under the heading **weightx, weighty**.

EDIT:

You also need to set the `fill` for the components, otherwise it defaults to `NONE`:

> **GridBagConstraints.fill**
>
> Used when the component's display area is larger than the component's requested size to determine whether (and how) to resize the component. Possible values are GridBagConstraints.NONE (the default), GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL (make the component wide enough to fill its display area horizontally, but don't change its height), GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL (make the component tall enough to fill its display area vertically, but don't change its width), and GridBagConstraints.BOTH (make the component fill its display area entirely).

Here is what I get by setting `weightx` to `0.33` for `explorerPanel` and `tagPanel`, and `0.66` for `secondaryPanel`, and setting `fill` to `GridBagConstraints.BOTH` for all of them:

[image]

Comment: Did not work neither, I tried it also before posting. Look at my edit.

Comment: Thank you glad3dr. It does answer part of the question but the proportions from the Panels are more respected in the other answer. Upvoted though. Thank you veru much for the help again. :)

Comment: It is possible to get whatever proportions you wish by changing the weightx and weighty values.

Comment: @YassinHajaj I've changed my edit to show how you can adjust the proportions.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by using BorderLayout

Rather than this:

```
    this.setContentPane(mainPanel);
```

You can do this:

```
getContentPane().add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: I tried this also before posting, not working but thanks for replying.